# replacing column values in a datatable and getting value in datatable datatype using linq

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have a datatable with 97 columns and in those 97 columns there is one column (for instance column number 20) where I have to add a single letter(A) to all the values in that particular row. How can I achieve this using linq?

I tried it to assign a select code to a variable but than I cannot use **New With** as I would have to write all the 97 columns in my **data row loader method**.

Is there a way to add dynamically add all column names when using new with method.

Thank you for your help

Also I have used:

```
DT.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(r) cstr(r("Account")).Replace(cstr(r("Account")),"'"+cstr(r("Account"))) ).ToList)
```

using this method but I get a list is there a way where I can put this list value in place of the column value?

Comment: All values in one row, or all values in one column of all records?

Comment: Without Linq this is much easier, a datareader can access columns with an index

Comment: hello @GertArnold all values in one column!!

Comment: hello @Luc can you tell me more about datareader i havent used it

Comment: This smells like poor database design. With proper normalization you probably could have modified only one value in one record. Anyway, don't use LINQ for this. Just execute a simple SQL update statement from your VB code.

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of silly to waste developer time on regex when the for loop is so easy. After all the regex is doing the loop behind the scenes.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        row(3) = "A" & row(3).ToString
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you understand what user wants?
If you want to change all the rows of that column, this is the best solution, but if you want to change a single row I suggest you regex
as windows libraries are in C and C treats memory differently than vb.net and is much more efficient.
It's a bit silly to call different solutions than your "It's a little silly"

Comment: hello @Mary your solution is great but i dont want to use for each as the records are way higher and it would take a lot of time for me to get the desired output.Thats why i am looking for a linq alternative....

Comment: @Vickydas Time it after you figure out the regex. The regex might even be slower.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. Quote stolen from someone who I failed to record. :-)

Comment: @Vickydas What about updating the database directly? Let the server do the work.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.
I write some info in the code comments

```
'In this mode you update the sixth row (only the column 20)
Dim query As EnumerableRowCollection(Of Object) = From dRow As DataRow In Dt.AsEnumerable()
                                                  Select col20 = dRow.Item(20)
                                                  Skip 5
                                                  Take 1



For Each Row As DataRow In query
    Row.Item(0) = "A"
Next


'In this mode you get all rows 
Dim queryAllRowData As EnumerableRowCollection(Of DataRow) = From dRow As DataRow In Dt.AsEnumerable()




For Each Row As DataRow In queryAllRowData
    Row.ItemArray = {"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"} ' put here (or do any method to give) your 90 column data
Next





'Don't forget commit changes
Dt.AcceptChanges()
```

Comment: Don't call `.AcceptChanges()` if you want to update the database. You can call that after an update.

Comment: It is assumed user is working with DB.
It is not clear what you want to say, but take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thank you for your time @G3nt_M3caj but as i said earlier i dont want to use for each

Comment: There is no "Linq" or equivalent method without doing the "For" cycle (I realized that you want to change the values of a column after your comments).
So the best solution is the one proposed by @Mary (error hunter) without duplicating the work load going from "Linq". Thanks for the reply

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj Calling `.AcceptChanges `updates the `DataRow` `.RowState` which makes it impossible to use a `DataAdapter` to update a datebase or to manually pull out rows by `.RowState` and update the database. From the link you posted "The RowState property of each DataRow also changes; Added and Modified rows become Unchanged, and Deleted rows are removed."

Comment: I saw that you always find something off topic (in your answers) .. But it's not a problem for me. Keep doing it

Comment: @Mary (error hunter but impossible) you is out of theme with your comments. If you want we can deepen but not in this question

Comment: @FuturePrincess here we didn't never talk about DataAdapter

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj I just don't like answers that might cause difficulties for the OP. AcceptChanges on a DataTable cascades to DataRow.AcceptChanges. If you posted it as part of your answer with a comment of "Don't forget" then it should be corrected. Not "out of theme"

Comment: I put my face in my answers. As you can see in the picture of my profile, and I'm not afraid even if I'm wrong. Making mistakes is human. It helps to grow (without ever considering itself a phenomenon). Abbraccio . (Have I made mistakes?)

Comment: hello @Mary and  thank you for your time.....So i used for each and updated and solved my query but what about my second question any solutions ?? 
 to use load data row method to add all the columns name one by one dynamically
how can i use data row loader or datatablevariable.add method and add n number of columns with new with method and not type it all one by one This is a sample code  DT.Clone.Rows.Add(y.ToString,x.ToString)).copytodatatable or like this

Comment: hello @G3nt_M3caj

Comment: @Vickydas Sorry, I don't understand what that last line of code is supposed to do. If half your problem is solved, accept an answer and ask a new question with your up to date code.

Comment: Hi @[Vickydas] ,@[Mary]. I’m afraid to missing this discussion (as you seen the last days I missing a lot of questions).
Even I’m busy, however, I’ll gladly stop by for a greeting. I hope you have a nice week. Thanks for your greeting .

Comment: hello @Mary my last question is still not answered its still related to this question what i am doing is first i am writing a linq query and assigning it to two variable x and y ........for e.g let x= dt.select(and my query).tolist now i want to add the values row by row so i am using dt.loaddatarow or dt.rows.add methods so now here lets take this code as example DT.Clone.Rows.Add(y.ToString,x.ToString)).copytodatatable i have to manually type all the column names here x and y are **the variable containing query** so what if i have 90 column how can i get all columns without manually typing.

Comment: @Vickydas I am very sorry, but you have lost me. A question should only have one question. Ask a new question with your code (not pseudo code).

Comment: ok no problem @Mary but thank you for your help have a great day ahead :)